# laravel 5.4 + php 7.0 error in Azure server

Tags: azure, laravel-5.4

I get this error in my project i am used Azure server 
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)**
I have use diffForHuman in my model to parse the date. my local server has running all perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change Your symfony version in  **vendor/laravel/framework/composer.json** 
folder. If version is > 3.3 then downgrade to 3.2 and then try.
After that `update composer`.